TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for S:\projects\sofie\rethink-backend\src\main\typescript\utils\CalculateAge.ts
I was trying to run this file using the command ts-node, then I got this error. I'd installed ts-node via npm, so I don't know why the error still occured.
TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for S:\projects\sofie\rethink-backend\src\main\typescript\utils\CalculateAge.ts
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:406:5)
    at Object.getFileProtocolModuleFormat [as file:] (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:99:9)
    at defaultGetFormat (node:internal/modules/esm/get_format:142:36)
    at defaultLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/load:120:20)
    at ModuleLoader.load (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:396:13)
    at ModuleLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:278:56)
    at new ModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:65:26)
    at ModuleLoader.#createModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:290:17)
    at ModuleLoader.getJobFromResolveResult (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:248:34)
    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:229:17) {
  code: 'ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION'
}


What command line did you use?
